# Show, that $\frac {E[Xg(X)]}{E[g(X)]} \ge E[X]$ when $g$ strictly monotonic increasing

Tags: probability, expected-value, covariance

Let $g:\mathbb R \to (0,\infty), X$ real valued random variable and $g(X) \in \mathcal L^2$ and $g$ strictly monotonic increasing.

Show, that $\frac {E[Xg(X)]}{E[g(X)]} \ge E[X]$

I tried something with expected values and their correlation with covariance, but I don't get the final result.

Comment: Strict inequality doesn't hold since $X$ could have been almost surely constant.

Comment: How would you argue for $\ge$ @user10354138

Comment: Is this homework?  Exam?  If the former, I can give a hint.  If the latter, I can give a maybe tiny tiny hint...?

Comment: @antkam It's from last years exam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since (the identity and) $g$ is strictly increasing, the covariance of $X$ and $g(X)$ is [nonnegative](/questions/74677).  Hence
$$
0\leq
\operatorname{Cov}(X,g(X))=
\mathbb{E}[Xg(X)]-\mathbb{E}[g(X)]\mathbb{E}X
$$
and we can divide by $\mathbb{E}[g(X)]>0$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a case of a more general inequality.

Hint: Let $f$ and $g$ both be monotonically increasing functions. Let $X_1, X_2$ be i.i.d. copies of $X$ and consider the sign of
$$ (g(X_1)-g(X_2))(f(X_1)-f(X_2)). $$